# SQL query to combine two different table structures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine the data from two different table structures into the one query. I think it can be done, but I am lost as to the syntax and way to go about it. Below are the structures of my two tables: Table 1 and Table 2. Table 1 was previous old data. New data was placed in a different structure, Table 2. The actual values are still the same, having two revenue types for which three business types can be assigned. Table 2 no longer needs     `BusinessTypeC` though, so is not included.     `BusinessTypeA` and     `BusinessTypeB` in Table 1 are just     `BusinessType` 1 and 2 in Table 2.

I know to `UNION` the data in the query, as the data do not overlap. But how would I make a new dataset in the query, essentially rebuilding Table 1 like Table 2, so they could     `UNION` and be one query dataset?

any ideas or pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated. If you need more detail please let me know! I have another few tables like this, but of the same problem. So I could apply the help here elsewhere!

`ReturnsID` and `SubmissionID` are dual primary keys. Sorry I would include some sample data but I do not know how to tag it or include it!

Table 1 structure:

```
>CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RevenueOLD](
[ReturnsID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SubmissionId] [int] NOT NULL,
[RevenueType] [int] NOT NULL,
[BusinessTypeA] [numeric](13, 2) NULL,
[BusinessTypeB] [numeric](13, 2) NULL,
[BusinessTypeC] [numeric](13, 2) NULL
```

Table 2 structure:

```
>CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RevenueNEW](
[ReturnsID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SubmissionId] [int] NOT NULL,
[RevenueType] [int] NOT NULL,
[BusinessType] [int] NOT NULL,
[Value] [numeric](13, 2) NULL
```

Comment: What's matching up with what?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard `[..]` "quoting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the structure from RevenueNEW, I think you need to union a query of it with three (or two if you don't care about BusinessTypeC) queries from RevenueOLD:

```
SELECT *
FROM RevenueNEW
UNION ALL
SELECT ReturnsID, SubmissionId, RevenueType,
    1 AS BusinessType, BusinessTypeA AS Value
FROM RevenueOLD WHERE ISNULL(BusinessTypeA, 0) <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT ReturnsID, SubmissionId, RevenueType,
    2 AS BusinessType, BusinessTypeB AS Value
FROM RevenueOLD WHERE ISNULL(BusinessTypeB, 0) <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT ReturnsID, SubmissionId, RevenueType,
    3 AS BusinessType, BusinessTypeC AS Value
FROM RevenueOLD WHERE ISNULL(BusinessTypeC, 0) <> 0
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jason! This keeps the exact format of the new table, while recoding the old to fit in. Was not sure or confident on the syntax. Exactly what I wanted with recoding the data with a 1 or 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    ReturnsID,
    SubmissionId,
    RevenueType,
    BusinessTypeA,
    BusinessTypeB,
    BusinessTypeC,
    NULL AS BusinessType,
    NULL AS Value
FROM
    RevenueOLD
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ReturnsID,
    SubmissionId,
    RevenueType,
    NULL AS BusinessTypeA,
    NULL AS BusinessTypeB,
    NULL AS BusinessTypeC,
    BusinessType,
    Value
FROM
    RevenueNEW
```

Comment: Thanks Arion - this worked however Jason's suggestion keeps the new table format which was what I was after. Thanks for your help though!